# What Program do I need to write .bib files and how do I use their contents in my bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, apa-style

What Program do I need to write .bib files and how do I use their contents to create my bibliography with the help of the additional input of my bst file which I downloaded from http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub//tex/bibtex/apa.bst (APA style)?

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 if it is relevant.

Comment: See: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management or every introduction of LaTeX

Comment: I couldn't understand it.

Comment: I think the repeating of the linked article can't be the aim. What is your main issue? A bib file can be created by every editor.

Comment: I want to have a nice and simply phrased guide as to how to do referencing with bibtex for APA and Oxford styles so that I can implement it in my documents. I would also appreciate a few examples of how to do it because I find examples fit my learning style better.

Comment: I think you need to be introduced to how BibTeX and LaTeX interacts. This is also not related to how you keep your bibliography database file wit the extension `.bib`. The quickest way to try out is JabRef. It's fairly easy to populate a database with it and you don't need any TeX knowledge to obtain a `.bib` file. If you alredy have a `.bib` file then you can look at the questions tagged with [tag:apa-style] and [tag:bibtex] for possible use cases.

Comment: `.bib` files follow a style-agnostic text-based format, so you only need to write a plain text file which complies with the spec, or use one of the GUI tools available for the task, e.g, [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/). The style will be determined according to the `\bibliographystyle` setting in your `.tex` file.

Comment: One starting point is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number

Comment: If this is your "first learning" of bibliographies in LaTeX, then I'd recommend you go the path of BibLaTeX, not BibTeX, which is showing its age. BibLaTeX does have an APA style.

Answer (score 3):

Let's demonstrate how you can achieve this with [`biblatex`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex), which comes with in-built support for [APA](http://www.library.cornell.edu/resrch/citmanage/apa) style; technically, we'll actually be using `biber`, which is a 'backend bibliography processor for `biblatex`'

We will have the following files in the same directory

**`myfile.tex`**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \verb!\cite! \cite{Ab_Steg}
  \item \verb!\textcite! \textcite{Ab_Steg}
  \item \verb!\parencite! \parencite{Ab_Steg}
\end{itemize}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**`mybib.bib`**

```
@BOOK{Ab_Steg,
 author = "M. Abramowitz and I. A. Stegun",
 title = {Handbook of mathematical functions},
 publisher = "Dover publications",
 year = "1965",
 language="English" }
```

To compile this, you run

```
pdflatex myfile
biber myfile
pdflatex myfile
pdflatex myfile
```

note that each command doesn't have an extension- if you wanted to, you could use the extensions

```
pdflatex myfile.tex
biber myfile.bcf
pdflatex myfile.tex
pdflatex myfile.tex
```

This gives the following output

[image: screenshot]

To facilitate this process we can use the excellent [`arara`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/arara) automation tool to help- we can change `myfile.tex` to include the following lines

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \verb!\cite! \cite{Ab_Steg}
  \item \verb!\textcite! \textcite{Ab_Steg}
  \item \verb!\parencite! \parencite{Ab_Steg}
\end{itemize}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

which gives

```
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _ 
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Running PDFLaTeX... SUCCESS
Running Biber... SUCCESS
Running PDFLaTeX... SUCCESS
Running PDFLaTeX... SUCCESS
```

Comment: For APA, it is better to use `biblatex-apa` (which requires `biber`): the authoryear style is not meant to be an implementation of the strict APA requirements.  Also, newer versions of `biblatex` encourage the use of `\addbibresource{<bibfile>.bib}` over the deprecated use of `\bibliography{<bibfile>}`.

Comment: I ran PDFLaTeX and received the error: ! LaTeX Error: File `biblatex.sty' not found.

Comment: @jon thanks for the corrections- I have updated with your feedback.

Comment: @BrentonHorne are you using the `texlive` from the repositories? If so, please see [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092) and also [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)

Comment: @cmhughes  -- No problem.  A nice and complete answer.

Comment: @BrentonHorne -- Can you explain how / from where you installed your system?

Comment: I am using Texmaker as my TeX/LaTeX compiler.

Comment: @BrentonHorne that's not really relevant :) it's the *distribution* that's important- meet me in the main chat room if you like

Comment: I have texlive installed so I assume I am using texlive.

Comment: @cmhughes I don't have much programming skill or experience so those two question pages don't really help me. Could you add some codes to your answer so I can overcome this problem?

Comment: I'm using texmaker and it doesn't have "biber" as an option. How do I compile? It has bibtex as an option, however. What do I do if I want to do a quick build and want to see my references?